# ASP.NET MVC3: Datetimepicker wont work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datetimepicker

I cant get the datetime picker working.

In the layout partial I have

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In my view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Insert Task";
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ActionDateTime').datetimepicker();
    </script>
}
```

Here is my field

```
@Html.Label("Action Date") @Html.TextBox("ActionDateTime")
```

**EDIT:**

So the page source now looks like this after applying changes:
In the head I have : (this is linked correctly, clicking link opens js file)

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the body I have :

```
    <input id="ActionDateTime" name="ActionDateTime" type="text" value="" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#ActionDateTime').datetimepicker();


        });

    </script>
```

Still not working.

Comment: Check the generated HTML output (view source in browser) to check whether the ActionDateTime textbox actually has the id 'ActionDateTime'.

Comment: I checked this already, but on the Name attribute. Is it the ID it looks for? EDIT, infact its in ID too anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetimepicker` is not part of the jQuery core library. You need to include this script along with the jQuery UI library.

`datetimepicker` plugin
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

jQuery UI library http://jqueryui.com/download

Include both in your head/or foot section where ever you have the reference to the jQuery library, BUT below the jQuery library reference.

Also include the jQuery UI stylesheet depending on the style you have selected.

Comment: Can you take a look at my Edit in my Q please, still not working

Comment: Have you added the reference to the jQuery UI Library? Also you need the jQuery UI Stylesheet

Comment: I added it to the scripts folder in solution explorer. It finds it fine on run time. Jquery Stylesheet?  I added the 5 lines of CSS mentioned on http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ . Ill try your suggested datetimepicker

Comment: You need 3 javascript files: jQuery, jQuery UI and the datetimepicker plugin. ALSO the jQuery UI stylesheet.

Comment: Excellent stuff. Following your link, I downloaded the datetimepicker, copied the example, of inline picker, then modified to myneeds. works great. Cheers for help

Comment: I think it is `$('#ActionDateTime').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});`

Answer (score 1):

I can see you have included the jQuery script, but have you also included the script for the DateTimePicker plugin?

From googling, [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) appears to be the plugin you're trying to use, so you'll need to download the `JS` from there, then add the following line underneath your current jQuery script line:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It would also be advisable to move your `<script>` tag out of the Razor code block, as there's no need for it to be there. Put it either in the `<head>` or just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Er um, and where would this be located? I assumed it was part of Jquery. (Asp.net mvc automatically adds jquery).

Comment: the DateTimePicker isn't part of jQuery's core. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `datetimepicker()` is not part of the jQuery core you need to add a script reference to the plugin like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-datetimepicker.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After this you should move the script block out of the curly brackets and place it somewhere beneath the input like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("ActionDateTime")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ActionDateTime').datetimepicker();
</script>
```

Nevertheless you should have a look at EditorTemplates, which helps you to keep your views clean.

Answer (score 1):

also add code inside `$(document).ready`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#ActionDateTime').datetimepicker();


});

</script>
```